# Работа с клавиатурой

Tags: c#, клавиатура

Привет всем.

Скажите, пожалуйста, как снести каретку при при нажатии на enter в указанный textBox.
Пример, как в форме регистрации, пользователь ввел строку "имя", нажал enter и каретка спустилась на следующую ячейку для ввода информации. Спасибо.

Comment: какой у вас фреймворк?

Comment: @NMD спасибо. Надеюсь, вас не затруднило ответить на этот вопрос :). Исходя из комментариев этого вопроса, все оказывается не все так просто

Comment: @Геннадий Писарев: Вопрос был о _графическом_ фреймворке. Например, WPF или WinForms. Каждый из них решает этот вопрос по-своему. А C# сам по себе вовсе не решает.

Comment: >Например, WPF или WinForms. Каждый из них решает этот вопрос по-своему

плюс еще это может быть asp.net или asp,net mvc - там тоже это будет выглядеть иначе.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Необходимо в textbox отлавливать нажатия клавиш, и когда будет нажата Enter, выполнить `{имя textbox'a}.Focus();`.

Типа вот так:

```
    private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
        {
            textBox2.Focus();
        }
    }
```

Comment: @NMD  Спасибо, все работает, все отлично. Из-за этой строки кода здесь чуть бы третья мировая началась :). Интересно только, почему на меня не налетели, когда я задал вопрос про комментарий.